# .NET SplitContainer using C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I've added a SplitContainer with a horizontal bar between the two panes.  I can add content, and move the bar up and down to resize the containers, but the bar itself is invisible.  I want the users of my application to see a visible split between these two areas.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the BorderStyle of the SplitContainer to FixedSingle or Fixed3D.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!  Sometimes I wish stuff like this was a little more obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be a theme with Microsoft controls.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the look you desire, you also might try adding objects that distinct borders to the 2 content panels in a manner that would cause the splitter to stand out.  This is how Outlook 2003/2007 handles split bars.